# How to whitelist only one path in kubernetes nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Using the Nginx Ingress Controller, we would like to expose different paths of a Kubernetes service, with different security requirements.

1. `/` is open to the public
2. `/white-list` only allows connections from a specific IP Address
3. `/need-key` requires an API key

I'm running in AWS EKS. Kubernetes version is as follows:`v1.12.6-eks-d69f1b`.

If we use Annotations, they apply to the entire service. Ideally I would like to apply an Annotation only to a path.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myServiceA
  annotations:
    # use the shared ingress-nginx
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myServiceA.foo.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myServiceA
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /white-list
        backend:
          serviceName: myServiceA
          servicePort: 80
          **NEED SOMETHING HERE TO WHITELIST**
      - path: /need-key
        backend:
          serviceName: myServiceA
          servicePort: 80
          **NEED SOMETHING HERE TO USE API-KEY**
```

The results I've been having end up applying to all the paths.
I can live without API-Key as I can code that out, but ideally, I'd rather have it managed outside of the container.

Has anyone accomplished this with NGINX Ingress controller?

Answer (score 8):

To apply annotation for each path, you could write one `ingress` rule for each path you want to apply. Nginx Ingress Controller will collect those `ingress` rules by itself and apply accordingly.

For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myServiceA-root
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myServiceA.foo.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myServiceA
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myServiceA-white-list
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: X.X.X.X/32
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myServiceA.foo.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /white-list
        backend:
          serviceName: myServiceA
          servicePort: 80
...
```