# nginx-ingress basic authentication for only a given path?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Using `nginx-ingress`, is it possible to enable basic authentication only for a given path (or enable it for all paths and exclude some paths from it)?

[The documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/) only shows how to protect all paths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a seperate ingress rule for your given path such that only this path is protected by basic authentication.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444440/how-to-whitelist-only-one-path-in-kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller/56453375#56453375) for examples.

Comment: ah great, didn't know that. Thank you! For the records: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/ confirms that merging is supported and doesn't only work by chance ;-)